# Multithreaded JNI-Calls

Tags: java, c++, c, multithreading, java-native-interface

I've learned that I have to attach the c-threads to the jvm with `jvm->AttachCurrentThread` everytime I use the `JNIEnv`. This should be quite similar to a mutex, I lock it with `jvm->AttachCurrentThread` at the beginning of the method and unlock it with `jvm->DetachCurrentThread()` at the end.
So, now I have a method where I use the `JNIEnv` moreoften. Do I have to call `AttachCurrentThread` everytime? Here you have a code sample:

```
  std::unique_ptr<IState> JNIGame::createEmptyState() {
    JNIEnv* env;
    jvm->AttachCurrentThread((void**)&env, NULL);
    if(!jGame_createEmptyState)
      jGame_createEmptyState =  env->GetMethodID(jGameC, "createEmptyState", "()Ljni/JNIGames$IJNIState;");

    JNIState *state = new JNIState();
    //needed?
    jvm->AttachCurrentThread((void**)&env, NULL);
    state->jStateO = env->CallObjectMethod(jGameO, jGame_createEmptyState);
    jvm->DetachCurrentThread();
    return std::unique_ptr<IState>(state);
}
```

As you see, I attach the thread two times, because without the second one, the code crashes. But if they act like mutex, only the first one would be needed. Could you help me, why I need them every time? Is it save like the code is now?

Comment: If you want to call C/C++ code from Java you should consider using some automatic tool, like SWIG.

Comment: I got a c++ framework and have to add an interface to java, so new implementations could be in java and use the old framework. The old framework uses threads, but I'm not allowed to change anything within the framework.

Comment: That's what SWIG is for. It eases the creation of bindings of existing C and C++ code to use from Java. You (mostly) don't need to care about low level JVM JNI stuff. http://www.swig.org/

Comment: @vz0 There are other IMHO easier-to-use tools, such as [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp) :)

Comment: I need it the other way around. Call Java methods from C++ side. But yesterday I've finished it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "act like a mutex," but the documentation says, "Trying to attach a thread that is already attached is a no-op."

Your example attaches twice, and then detaches once.  The second attach has no effect.

That sentence I quoted came from the "Invocation API" chapter of the JNI doc.  "Invocation API" is what they call the collected methods that you need to call Java from C (as opposed to the ones that you use to write native methods that you can call *from* Java.)

---

A couple of points worth mentioning:

The thread that starts the JVM is implicitly attached.  That thread becomes the JVM's "main" thread.

The JVM will shut down (can't be restarted) whenever the last non-daemon thread exits.  If a native thread detaches, that is counted as a thread exit.

My application has a dedicated "main" thread that starts the JVM, notifies other threads that it is started, and then sleeps forever.  The sleeping "main" thread is what keeps my JVM alive when none of my app's other native threads are using it.

Comment: ``If a native thread detaches, that is counted as a thread exit.``
Thank you very much. I removed all detaches and changed all attaches to Daemons, it is running as planned now.

Comment: `That thread becomes the JVM's "main" thread`. What do you by "main" here? You mean that the current thread become JVM internal main thread(that is used by JVM for its own stuff) or you mean that it becomes actually the main thread of Java execution(the one that calls `public static void main`) ? thank you

Comment: @AndreLiberty, I'm sorry, but that answer is more than six hears old. It's been almost that long since the last time I touched code that called the invocation API. I don't remember why I said that. It sounds like an easy test though: Invoke a Java program whose `main()` returns after creating a new, non-daemon thread that lives forever. Then it's a simple matter of noticing whether or not the C function call that started the JVM returns.

Comment: Sorry, my bad that I didn't take a look on the post date. And thank you for the reply

Answer (score 0):

`AttachCurrentThread` allows to add a thread you have created outside the JVM to be added to the Java Virtual Machine. It is not intended to be called “everytime you use the `JNIEnv`” and is by no means “similar to a mutex”.

Further, to cite [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#attach_current_thread):

> Trying to attach a thread that is already attached is a no-op.

If your code crashes, it might be because of the very fact that `AttachCurrentThread` is *not* a mutex. If your method `JNIGame::createEmptyState()` is called by multiple threads you have to use a real mutex.

Normally, when interacting with a virtual machine, you attach a thread once and keep it attached for a longer time instead of detaching it after every single method.